# Setting data in Primefaces 3.5 to desired object variable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

My code is :

```
<p:inputText id="creditHr" 
    value="#{cpeTrainingMB.cpeTrainingScheObj.creditHr}" required="true" 
    requiredMessage="Please Enter Credit Hour"/>
```

Here I have 'cpeTrainingMB' as mangaged bean as ViewScooped and 
cpeTrainingScheObj as model class object and creditHr is 'int' type.
Recently it is misbehaving. As I set the data, it always sets the default 'int' value as '0' (zero), even if I set the data in text field as other than zero.

Comment: The default value of an unassigned int is 0. This is standard java primitives you'll need to attach a converter or extra validation. Generally the conversion would be done later otherwise your field will always show 0.

Comment: Also, check whether you have getter and setter for your attribute in your managed bean.

Comment: I have getter and setter for the attribute and other fields associated with the object other than creditHr, has the value set as set in the UI. Only the field creditHr is not working now, before it was working well and the value was set as inserted from the UI.